# Looking for alternative to set of nested #ifdef-s

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to add the following concept into my C code (`CMAKE_*` defines are independent from each other):

```
#define DEF N

#ifdef CMAKE_X
redefine DEF (DEF + CMAKE_X)
#endif

#ifdef CMAKE_Y
redefine DEF (DEF + CMAKE_Y)
#endif

#ifdef CMAKE_Z
redefine DEF (DEF + CMAKE_Z)
#endif

...
```

I'm looking for any way better than a big complex set of nested ifdef-s statements. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Describe what you want to do. This is way to fuzzy.

Comment: How about defining `DEF`, `DEF_X`, `DEF_Y`... and adding them all at the end?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're looking for something like this:

```
#define DEF_0 N

#ifdef CMAKE_X
#define DEF_X (DEF_0 + CMAKE_X)
#else
#define DEF_X DEF_0
#endif

#ifdef CMAKE_Y
#define DEF_Y (DEF_X + CMAKE_Y)
#else
#define DEF_Y DEF_X
#endif

#ifdef CMAKE_Z
redefine DEF_Z (DEF_Y + CMAKE_Z)
#else
#define DEF_Z DEF_Y
#endif

#define DEF DEF_Z
```

I.e. build up intermediate macros, each of which may or may not have additions to the previous one.